# Unable to connect to MySQL DB on Windows

Tags: mysql, ballerina

My connection string looks like this:

```
jdbc:Client DB = new ({
    url: "jdbc:mysql://[ip]/[dbName]",
    username: "[username]",
    password: "[password]",
    poolOptions: {maximumPoolSize: 5},
    dbOptions: {useSSL: false}
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error: {ballerinax/java.jdbc}ApplicationError message=error in sql connector configuration: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://[ip]/[dbName] suitable driver
        at ballerinax.java_jdbc:createClient(jdbc_client.bal:87)
           ballerinax.java_jdbc.Client:__init(client_endpoint.bal:27)
           ..<init>(.:5)
```

Did I format the URL not in the intended way?

P.S: The database works and is accessible, I am using it in other projects in .net core 3.

Comment: How do you run the ballerina program? Just a `ballerina run example.bal` or are you creating a jar and run it?

Comment: ballerina run example.bal

Comment: I tried creating a .jar and running it just now, the error is the same.

Comment: Ballerina distribution doesn't contain any driver libraries. You have to point that through a toml file as specified by Dhananjaya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the JDBC driver to the project by editing Ballerina.toml file. In this case you need to have the Ballerina files in Ballerina project/module.

```
[project]
org-name= "sample"
version= "0.1.0"

[platform]
target = "java8"

[[platform.libraries]]
    artafactId = "mysql-connector-java"
    version = "8.0.17"
    path = "/path/to/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar"
    groupId = "mysql"
    modules = ["samplemodule"]
```

Code sample taken from [Ballerina JDBC doc](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/java.jdbc/index.html), `path` here should be relative to .toml file location.

Adding from ThisaruG's comment:
Ballerina 1.0.x does not seems to support external dependencies when executing individual Ballerina files, hence the approach to use JDBC drivers with Ballerina is to create a module, add the JDBC dependency to .toml file and executing the module.

Comment: No I haven't, I was looking at the examples: [link](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-client-call-procedures.html). It wasn't mentioned there.

I added this and it still didn't work.

Is the name of the file important? I didn't have this file before, is this all the content needed for it? Do I need to include it somehow in the build command?

Comment: The example mension that you need . to add mysql-connector jar to BALLERINA_HOME/bre/lib if you can do that then you don't have to add it jar path in TOML file.

Comment: Download the mysql connector jar if you haven't already from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ (specific version doesn't matter for Ballerina) it may matter for your Database.

Comment: I already had the jar in BALLERINA_HOME/bre/lib when I posted the question.
I will try different version of the driver to see if that helps.
Does it matter that there will be multiple versions in BALLERINA_HOME/bre/lib?

What exactly should the .toml file contain and what name should it have if I decide to use it? (because the content provided above doesn't seem to do anything).

Comment: `ballerina run [module]` works
`ballerina run file.bal` does not.
why is that?

Comment: @GrigoreCaraman Since Ballerina 1.0.0 you can't use external dependencies with single `.bal` files. You have to use modules.

Comment: Dhananjaya, please add details to your answer. It partially helped me. If I had I known what @ThisaruG said, I would have solved my problem much quicker.

Comment: @Grigore I'm sorry for any misunderstanding, updated my answer.